# SimpleXML weird behavior while loading from string

Tags: php, simplexml

I've a really long XML, and I'm using `simplexml_load_string` in PHP to work on that. I'm facing a really weird behavior.

Here is the XML, I've shorted this part which is troubling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test><Customer></Customer><Comments><CustomerComment></CustomerComment></Comments></test>
```

I'm saving this value as a `string`. Here is my PHP code.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test><Customer></Customer><Comments><CustomerComment></CustomerComment></Comments></test>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($xml);
```

Here is the output

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["Customer"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
  ["Comments"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I've no idea, what's wrong with this simple code, and why it is not able to maintain child name `CustomerComment`. Googled a lot, couldn't find anything relevant yet.

Here is the weird this about it. I've removed the `Customer` child from root of XML tree, and it is getting child name correctly.

```
php > $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
php ' <order><Comments><CustomerComment></CustomerComment></Comments></order>';
php > $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
php > var_dump($xml);
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["Comments"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["CustomerComment"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Now actual weird part is, if I break the XML tree as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
<Customer></Customer>
<Comments>
<CustomerComment></CustomerComment>
</Comments>
</order>
```

Here is the `var_dump`.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["Customer"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {
  }
  ["Comments"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["CustomerComment"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

It is getting correct child name, but the XML is same as the 1st example (except line breaks)

Please can someone point out, what is wrong here?, and what can be done as a work-around for this problem. I'm guessing problem is with same child name in a single line (`Customer` in this instant).

Only possible work-around I can think of is to replace `>` with `>\n` in my XML string.

Comment: So, uh, which bit do you think is weird behaviour? The zero index? Can't replicate. Please provide a repeatable example so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @JonStirling updated question, please have a look

Comment: Oddly enough, the output is different depending on PHP version (see https://3v4l.org/cKfMc). Though SimpleXML is generally well known for it's odd dump output. Is this actually causing a problem?

Comment: I'm later converting it to JSON, where my code is breaking, because of this uncertain key. I thought of additionally making a check for this specific, but that won't be a global solution, as I might run in to this bug in future for any other child.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realise that **SimpleXML does not convert your XML into an array or hierarchy of objects**. Like the DOM, SimpleXML is an **API** for accessing your XML (but a much nicer one to work with!); therefore using `var_dump`, or blindly converting to JSON, will not give a useful result. Instead, use the APIs provided by SimpleXML to extract **the data you actually need** from the XML document.

In this case, you will find that, **as an API**, both `$xml->Comments->CustomerComment` and `$xml->Comments[0]->CustomerComment` return the same element (this is great if you don't know in advance whether someone's going to add a second `Comments` element). When dumping the output (or converting to a flat array) SimpleXML has to guess which of those to show you. It seems some versions of PHP had a bug where it showed the `0` rather than skipping straight to the `CustomerComment`, but the simple fact is **you shouldn't be relying on this anyway**, just access the nodes that you know you need.